# Windows 10: Cursor remains a pointer in Excel on extended display

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, mouse

When working in Excel, the cursor remains a pointer when I drag and fill the cells, it should be a Cross/Plus icon. it does turn to a vertical line when you type. Issue started last week after the system updates were installed. it does not affect excel to function but it's just very annoying. Have tried the following but no luck:

- restarting
- Unplug cable / plug it back in
- run compatibility troubleshooting on excel
- changed scaling of display
- updated drivers for mouse and display

any ideas folks? Thanks

Comment: issue only on extended displays. cursor works perfectly fine on my laptop builtin screen...

Answer (score 1):

I think you're talking about the fill handle. You can turn it on in the Excel option window.

Click on File > Options > Advanced and make sure the box "Enable fill handle and cell drag-and-drop" is checked.

[image: Excel - Fill Handle]

But this issue should not be only when you duplicate the screen

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue.  It turned out to be my docking station.  I powered off and powered on the docking station and the issue went away.

Answer (score 1):

Restarting the dock fixed my issues as well.  Previously I had restarted laptop, tried an Office repair, played with all kinds of features in excel & accessibility in case I accidentally activated something in error. Resizing tables in outlook were also failing along with the Excel issues with the pointer.  Turning off the dock made everything work again on my laptop, then turning back on dock made everything work again on monitors as well.   Thanks so much VLG!

Comment: This should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Man, I'd tried everything from BIOS updates, firmware updates, restarts etc...
Turns out power cycling the dock was the trick. Im almost annoyed it was that easy.